# How to set editText input into textView from alertDialog

Tags: android

I just want to have `TextView` turn into the input from `EditText`, but it does not work. Also this is in a custom array adapter not an `Activity` if that makes any difference. Also I had it working and I changed the orientation in `AndroidManifest.xml` I then changed it back to the default and `EditText` input no longer changed the `TextView`.

I even used VCS local history to go back to my previous code I have no idea what happened. Here's my code.

```
class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter{

    public CustomAdapter(Context context, ArrayList choreText) {
        super(context, R.layout.custon_listview_row, choreText);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater myInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        View customView = myInflater.inflate(R.layout.custon_listview_row, parent, false);
        ImageButton imageButton = (ImageButton) customView.findViewById(R.id.imageButton_ID);
        final TextView textView = (TextView) customView.findViewById(R.id.textView_ID);
        final EditText input = new EditText(getContext());
        final AlertDialog OptionDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext()).create();

        // makes textView clickable
        textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //what happens when textView is clicked

                //final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
                // put aler dialog box logic here
                OptionDialog.setTitle("Enter new chore");
                OptionDialog.setView(input);
                input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
                input.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);
                //checks if "Done" button on soft keyboard is clicked
                input.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
                        if(actionId==EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE){
                            //what happens when "Done" is clicked
                            textView.setText(input.getText().toString());
                            OptionDialog.dismiss();

                        }
                        return false;
                    }
                });

                OptionDialog.show();
            }
        });

        imageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.clock);

        return customView;
    }
}
```

Comment: "it does not work" How far is it work ? Is it crashes or what?

Comment: It all around works just the textView doesn't change into user input. It stays the same.

Comment: then check  if(actionId==EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE){//} weather this block executes put a log at the first line inside this and see if it gets called

Comment: I checked and it does work.

Comment: You can use edit text in place of TextView and disable Edit text and then want to take inpout then enable Edit Text .

Answer (score 0):

Edit text initailised above oncreate and indexed inside onCreate()

```
EditText editText;
onCreate()
 editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
```

//Call the dialog and proceed

```
 Button saveButton = (Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.saveButton);
    saveButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            String text = ((EditText)dialog.findViewById(R.id.text)).getText().toString();
            editText.setText(text);
        }
    });
```

U can keep a button in the dialog box and or u can proceed with ur way itself but need to